# Querying a simple xml file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file with two main categories, lets say:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <element1>value</element1>
    <element2>value</element2>
      ...
  </B>
</A>
```

The thing is that I've been trying to read it with Xlinq but I wasn't able to get those values.

I've been searching here:
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LinqToXML5MinuteOVerview.ashx
here: [Querying XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537879/querying-xml-file)
here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML-LINQ/XDocument.htm
here: http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3840141/Converting-Data-to-XML-with-LINQ-to-XML.htm
And on O'reilly Head First Csharp, Professional ASP.NET4 Csharp.

After all my research I didn't find two similar ways to do the same thing (which is good in terms of variety), but now all I have in my mind is a bunch of fixed examples, nothing in general. No reference libraries...So, where did you guys learn to use Xlinq?

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you've tried or where you've gone wrong. I normally just consult the documentation. If you can give a short but *complete* example (including complete XML) then we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I was forgetting to add the Namespace when refering to the Elements. After that It was a piece of cake to easy navigate through the xml file. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Path to your xml file");
 List<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants("element").ToList();
 foreach (XElement element in elements)
 {
     // You have your <element>value1</element> here, do whatever you want to do here.
 }
```

Comment: It didn't work. Everything I've tried inside the Descendants method has not given me the correct behaviour.

Comment: Finally Worked but without using anything in the brackets of Descendants method (don't ask me why). Thanks for your help. BTW, your second line needed a .toList() to make it work propperly.